# Media Query - not recognized in browser

Tags: css, media-queries, viewport

I'm truely baffled by Media Queries, i've been trying to get this issue to work but I just can't seem to pin-point where the problem lies.
I'm building a website with Wordpress and my header.php has the following line:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
    @media and (max-width: 800px) {styling parameters}
```

The first line refers to my header.php has the meta name="viewport" line that I provided in the previous msg and the second line of code is from my stylesheet (style.css) has the standard '@media and (max-width:800px {styling pararmeters}' syntax.

I've tried several different combinations for both lines of code but nothing seems to work,btw the media query properties have been entered at the end of the style sheet.

Any help will be very much appreciated

Regards
Ofer
Ofer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Media Query working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298115/why-isnt-my-media-query-working)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the position to move your media query higher up. I've discovered that wordpress the way it caches sometimes the media query happens too late and it won't get picked up.